# Getting error while executing

Tags: apex, batch

**While i am going to execute this batch class in debug log then i am getting this error (First error: Too many query rows: 50001) in debug log instead of updating the records.**

```
global class Example2Batch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{
    
    global Integer totalsize=0;
    global Integer Success_size=0;
    global Integer Fail_size=0;
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

       String query='Select id,Name,Fax,Email,MobilePhone,Description,Account.Name,Account.rating,Account.Phone,Account.Fax from contact LIMIT 50000';

      
       return Database.getQueryLocator(query);}

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> Contactlist)

    {
         Integer size=Contactlist.size();
        Totalsize=Totalsize+size;
         For(Integer i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            Contact con= Contactlist.get(i);
            if(con.Fax != null || con.Fax !='')
            {
                con.Fax= con.Account.Fax;
            }
            if(con.MobilePhone != null || con.MobilePhone != '')
            {
                con.MobilePhone= con.Account.Phone;
            }
            con.Email='Aashish.154000@gmail.com';
            con.Description= con.Account.Name+' '+con.Account.Rating+' '+con.Email;
        }
       List<Database.SaveResult> result=Database.update(Contactlist,false);
        Integer Sizeresult= result.size();
        for(Integer i=0; i<Sizeresult; i++)
        {
            Database.SaveResult sr= result.get(i);
            If(sr.isSuccess())
            {
                Success_size= Success_size+1;
            }
            else
            {
                Fail_size=Fail_size+1;
            }
        }
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
         Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email= new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        email.setSubject('Status of Batch Class: Contact Batch' );
        email.setSenderDisplayName('SFDC Partner Demo');
        email.setHtmlBody('Dear User, Batch Processed'+
                         '<br/> Total Records:'+totalsize+
                         '<br/> Success Records:'+Success_size+
                         '<br/> Fail Records:'+Fail_size);
        List<String> emailto= new List<String>();
        emailto.add('Aashish.154000@gmail.com');
        email.setToAddresses(emailto);
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailList=new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        emailList.add(email);
        Messaging.sendEmail(emailList,false);
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in this code that would cause that error; you don't even need the LIMIT 50000 in your code, assuming your intent is to update all records that need to be updated:

```
   return Database.getQueryLocator(
       [Select Fax,MobilePhone,Email,Account.Phone,Account.Fax,Account.Name,Account.Rating
        from contact]
   );
```

Your code confuses `||` for `&&` and `!=` for `==`; this is going to update all records incorrectly. You'd want:

```
for(Contact record: Contactlist) {
    if(record.Fax == null) {
        record.Fax = record.Account.Fax;
    }
    if(record.MobilePhone == null) {
        record.MobilePhone = record.Account.Phone;
    }
    record.Description = record.Account.Name + ' ' + record.Account.Rating + ' ' + record.Email;
}
for(Database.saveResult result: Database.update(Contactlist, false)) {
    if(result.isSuccess()) {
        Success_size++;
    } else {
        Fail_size++;
    }
}
```

Fields retrieved from the database will always be null, never an empty string. In addition, I presume you're trying to overwrite values only when the field is null.

In the original code, you tried: `field != null || field != ''`. This is always true, because if the field is null, it is not an empty string, and vice versa. The correct form of this logic is: `field != null && field != ''`, but we end up not needing that distinction in your code, as per above.

As far as the 50,001 error, it's not because of this code specifically. You have a database trigger that is querying too many records. You will need to trace through your code to determine what trigger is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox  for your quick and helpful response.

i got the problem there is a active trigger on the contact object in my org due to which i was facing this issue. when i disabled it then this batch class is working perfectly.